# I have to have this specfic boolean method return true if all the numbers in an array are positive

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Please point me in the right direction it doesn't seem to return false when I input negative numbers

```
public static boolean allPositive (int[] array){
 for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){ 
  if (array[i] <  0){
    return false; 
  }
}
 return true;
}
```

I expect the output to true or false depending on the array.

Comment: Just ran your code and it works fine. What numbers are you trying to put in?

Comment: Please post the array that you're sending to this method. Everything looks fine to me.

Comment: Your code works fine. Provide the array you're trying to use.

Comment: Edge-case: Returns `true` for an empty array (but I would say that is correct behaviour).

Comment: Treatment of `0` is maybe a bit underspecified.

Comment: I am trying a set of 6 numbers into an array mostly different numbers every time but mostly negative and it is still giving me back true

Comment: Please don't put code into comments; if it is relevant to the question, make an edit and format properly. That said, it would depend upon what the values are. This is why writing test cases is important rather than just trying to drive through the UI. This test input `int[] negs = { 1, 2, 3, 4, -5, 7 };` returns false as expected. Quick demo at https://ideone.com/X3VNSQ

Comment: oh okay sorry about that! i am going to check it out thank you.